# Redirect a wild card URL to another custom URL

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect a URL with parameters to a custom URL in htaccess.

```
example.com/folder?misc-params-that-can-change
```

should redirect to

```
my.customlink.com
```

I don't know how to write the wildcard for the parameters that start with the question mark.

This is where I'm at now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder [NC]
RwriteRule ^folder?(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a free coding service. The introduction _clearly_ states that you need to be able to use the tools yourself, so you need to attempt to write your own code and show it.

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the official documentation of the apache http server's rewriting module: you will find that you need to use a `RewriteCond` to match the query string. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I'm sorry if it seemed that way, I updated the original post to show where I am at now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

- You cannot match query string in the pattern of `RewriteRule`, need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in `RewriteCond` construct for this purpose.
- `?` after target URL is used to discard previous query string.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't redirect example.com/folder?param1 to google.com

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't work for me. I tried with and without a trailing slash after /folder , but no luck :(

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood. I need to redirect www.example.com/folder?whatever to www.google.com. So the params from the source URL should be stripped, not added to the destination URL. Thanks.

Comment: ok in that case use my updated rule. If it still doesn't work for you then please provide additional information I have requested.